# Middleware to serve static files from external Url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I currently have almost 500 image files in wwwroot/img folder. And my Git repository is bloated at the moment. I was wondering if there is a way to serve from another URL ?

I have another server where I can upload these images. A location like

[www.anotherDomain.com/images](http://www.anotherDomain.com/images)

However, I want to serve the static files but by creating my own path.

As an example: What if I want to serve images from [www.anotherDomain.com/images](http://www.anotherDomain.com/images) as www.myapp/admin/images, so I am not exposing [www.anotherDomain.com/images](http://www.anotherDomain.com/images) ?

In startup.cs,  I have done the following

```
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new StreamConfigurationProvider( PhysicalFileProvider("www.anotherDomain.com/images"),
            RequestPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/admin")
          
        });
```

This is asking for an absolute path. Unfortunately, I can not map the network drive since the anotherDomain.com/images is hosted in an old VM (where I intend to upload all images) and my application is hosted on Azure App Service.

Comment: One solution the problem of the images bloating the Git repo is to tell git to ignore the folder they are in.  You can learn more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repositories-on-windows